# Tell me about the expression 'shoot something to sunshine'

Tags: phrase-usage

> [shot to sunshine](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shot+to+sunshine)
>
> worn out, ruined, gone bad
>
> My privacy's been shot to sunshine, what with all these reporters.
>
> This carpet's been shot to sunshine.
>
> (UD)

I couldn't find the expression 'shoot something to sunshine' anywhere except the Urban Dictionary (according to it, it basically means "ruin [a plan etc.]"). Does it mean it's very slangy, rare, or it's not an idiom at all? Where does it even come from (optional question)?

Comment: Can't find it in TUD. Can you give me a link? TUD is uncurated. I wouldn't trust a citation that gives no references, hypothetical references, or personal anecdotes as references. I checked a couple of English corpora and got no results for the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a euphemistic version of **shot to *shit***. I can't say that it's common, specifically the *shit → sunshine* part. But in the right context, it should be understandable. This usage of *shot*, *to shit*, and *shot to shit* seem common enough to me. And I would say the UD entry is fairly accurate: when something has worn out, been ruined, gone bad, malfunctioned, broken down, gotten worse, etc. The example that came to mind was *the engine's shot to shit.* It's somewhat similar to *go to shit* below.

> [shot](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shot)   adjective
>   3 : reduced to a ruined or useless state his
>   // nerves are shot
>   (M-W)

I would say *to shit* is a sort of intensifier. It's also seen in *go to shit*:

> [shit<sup>2</sup>](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/shit) noun
>   2 something bad [uncountable] something that you think is bad or of very bad quality, or a bad situation
>   I’m not eating that shit!
>   piece/pile/load etc of shit
>   (Longman)
>
> [go to shit](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/go_to_shit) (third-person singular simple present goes to shit, present participle going to shit, simple past went to shit, past participle gone to shit)
>
> 1. (slang, vulgar) To completely fail; to have no result.
>      *All his hard work **went to shit** when the company filed for bankruptcy.*
> 2. (slang, vulgar) To become much worse.
>      *This city has **gone to shit** ever since he became mayor.*
>
> (Wiktionary)